# Capture keyword used when user clicks on adwords ad

Tags: keyword, google-ads-api

I wanted to know if it is possible to be able to capture the keyword that was searched when the user clicks on one of my ads. For instance say a user searches for "HVAC Installation" I would like to match a lead with a particular keyword searched for. Is that possible?

I'm assuming maybe from a POST I could capture the keyword?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the keyword as the user is entering your site, take a look at ValueTrack parameters, especially `matchtype` and `keyword`: [ValueTrack documentation at support.google.com](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447)

On the other hand, there's the `Search Query Performance Report` which gives you detailed statistics for every search term that caused at least one impression of your ads for a given time frame. It's available under the "Dimensions" tab in the Adwords Web UI or using the ad-hoc reporting functionality of the Adwords API: [Report definition at developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports?csw=1#search-query).